# Reverse Loop - count down cells to 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have never done a loop in VBA before and i am stuck.  I have found numerous example on the web and here and can't seem to tweak it to get it to do what i want.  So i would appreciate your help!

Basically i am creating a document revision table, the current revision comes in from another sheet and is entered into a cell, the loop i want to take that cell - 1 in the next cell down until it gets to 1.  Example if `.range("A1")` = 5 then A2 = 4, A3 = 3 A4 = 2 and A5 = 1.  This is my attempt at it.

```
Sub RevisionLoop()
Dim Rev As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Rev = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
Do While Rev > 0
Range("A1").Offset(i, 0) = Rev
i = i - 1
Rev = Rev - 1
Loop
End Sub
```

The minimum number will be 1.  Can you advise where i have gone wrong please? Also i am not to sure if my first `Dim` should be a `String` as i don't fully understand these yet. :-S Thank you!

Comment: Seems i instantiates at 0 and decrements from there, going negative. Is that intended?

Comment: Hi Joel, no, but i am not to sure what i am doing, so if i make `i = .range("A1")` would that work? Thank you

Comment: This, maybe? https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/a-vba-for-loop-in-reverse-order

Comment: Hi Joel, That has helped thank you. Far simpler than what i was trying to do. `Sub ReverseLoop()
Dim x As Long

'Loop Through 1-Range("A1") in Reverse Order
  For x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") To 1 Step -1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value = x
  Next x

End Sub`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is find the last row in your sheet.
Then instead of the Do While loop, use a loop instead.
Your loop should include "Step -1" in order to work from last to first (reverse order).

```
Sub FindLastRowInOneColumn_then_LoopInReverse()
    'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Loop Through All Rows in Reverse Order
        For x = LastRow To 0 Step -1
            'Change The Value In Column A to x
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value = x
        Next x
End Sub
```

Reference 1: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm
Referecne 2: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/a-vba-for-loop-in-reverse-order